# Charts (graphics) in iOS Notification Center?

Tags: ios, charts, notificationcenter

I have been searching for an app that can display currency-vs-currency (say over a week, 3 months and etc) chart in iOS Notification Center. But they don't seem to exist.

I don't mind writing one myself just for the fun of it, but does anyone know if Apple actually disallow this behaviour? I think it's more likely that Apple disallow this than nobody would have thought about this use case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Apple shows stocks and weather information in the notification center. So why not currencies?

Make it useful and beautiful, do not cross any of Apple's guidelines, and you'll get into the Appstore in no time - and may even get a lot of downloads from people who are into Stocks...